# How to remove short lines of text from a file

Tags: file, go

I am trying to write a Go program that will read a .txt file and will remove all lines that are shorter than the specified amount.
I am trying to do it as I am reading the file, it actually does find all the lines that are 2 symbols long, but doesn't remove them.

```
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(file)
    var bs []byte
    buf := bytes.NewBuffer(bs)
    
    var text string
    for scanner.Scan() {
        text = scanner.Text()
        length := len(text)
        if length < 3 {
            _, err := buf.WriteString("\n")
            if err != nil {
                exit("Couldn't replace line")
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What are you doing with `buf`?

Comment: @gopher Yes, thank you, I forgot to add `os.WriteFile`  at the end of my program.

Answer (score 1):

Your program is missing two things, first you should write the contents of the line to `buf`, so `_, err := buf.WriteString("\n")` could be rewritten as:

```
_, err := buf.WriteString(text + "\n")
```

The second thing is the removal code, the simplest approach could be to use both `Seek` and `Truncate` before dumping the contents of `buf` to the file handler:

```
// Reset the file size
f.Truncate(0)
// Position on the beginning of the file:
f.Seek(0, 0)
// Finally write the contents of buf into the file:
buf.WriteTo(f)
```

The full program would look like:

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "bytes"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    f, err := os.OpenFile("input.txt", os.O_RDWR, 0644)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(f)
    var bs []byte
    buf := bytes.NewBuffer(bs)

    var text string
    for scanner.Scan() {
        text = scanner.Text()
        length := len(text)
        if length < 3 {
            _, err := buf.WriteString(text + "\n")
            if err != nil {
                panic("Couldn't replace line")
            }
        }
    }
    f.Truncate(0)
    f.Seek(0, 0)
    buf.WriteTo(f)
}
```

Comment: 0755 is not an appropriate mode for a file that cannot be executed.  It should be 0644.  Also, shouldn't that be `length>3`?

Comment: @DanielFarrell makes sense. I've copied the same length condition that's used on the OP code.